# My Wingpanel bar is suddenly black with and without fullscreen app

Tags: wingpanel, desktop

Yesterday, I decide to change my icon set to Numix. I didn't like the look with numix inherit icons, so I change to elementary.

Then I notice that the WingPanel was always black. When there is not a fullscreen it is has is semi transparent and when there is a fullscreen it is black.

I do my research on the net and i found a way to fix it with dconf and autoadjust-alpha. It works, but when i restart it is the same: The panel is semi transparent (instead of completely transparent)

What can I do?

Sorry about my english, and thanks for the support!

Comment: Numix cannot break wingpanel

Comment: i have the same problem
please help

Answer (score 1):

This has basically been asked. This should fix your problem:

[How to adjust wingpanel transparency in loki?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7734/how-to-adjust-wingpanel-transparency-in-loki)

If not, I would suggest changing to a different theme then back to elementary. Since the wingpanel theme is dictated by the GTK theme this might just reset things back to the way they should be.