# How to adjust wingpanel transparency in loki?

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel

I'm not able to adjust the transparency of wingpanel using gsettings/tweaks. Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Type `gksu scratch-text-editor "/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css"`  in terminal and go search pannel class in the css file, there u can set the colors, opacity and so on. This is what I did today!

In case u dont have gksu, type

```
sudo apt install gksu
```

DON'T forget to REBOOT !

Answer (score 0):

This is set in the gtk theme now.

https://github.com/elementary/stylesheet/blob/master/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css#L292

Comment: Djax just notified me I didn't drink enough coffee this morning....ignore whatever I had written before here and follow his guru-ed sage advice. Thanks Djax...climbing over the wall right now to go get some coffee

Comment: How do I change it ?

Comment: IMO this answer needs to be developed a bit more. Specifically, what implications does being in the Gtk theme have on the original question? I.e. is there a way to change this or not?

Comment: As said, the transparency is set in the gtk theme in the panel section. There are different modes and so different colors and stuff in each mode. The transparency is the second value in the alpha method. I don't recommend to mess with it if you don't know css..

Comment: Error 404: Page not found